# How do I persist an Entity which implements Collection

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a class which implements java.util.Collection and is also annotated as an @Entity.  How do I persist that class as an `Entity` rather than a `Collection`.

I am trying to use `EntityManager.persist(Object entity)`, but that is throwing an exception from spring-data stating:

> org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type java.lang.Object!

This used to work when using spring-boot 2.0.7.RELEASE, but I am trying to upgrade to spring-boot 2.1.1.RELEASE (which uses spring-data-jpa:2.1.3.RELEASE).

From what I can tell, there is a "new" `PersistentPropertyPathFactory` that now uses the "actualType" to determine what type the Entity is that needs to be persisted.  However, the "actualType" for my Entity ends up just be `java.lang.Object` because it `isCollectionLike` (i.e. my type is a Collection so it satisfies the `Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(rawType)` check).

What I would really like is to have my Entity persisted as its own type rather than having the EntityManager trying to persist it as a Collection.

Does anyone know of how to do this or is there some documentation that states an Entity should not be a Collection?

Here is a simplified example of the Entity/Collection class:

```
@Entity
public class ContainerCollection<C extends Container> extends Container implements Collection<C> {

    @JoinTable(
        name = "mod_container_collections",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "container_collection_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "container_id"))
    protected Set<C> containers = new HashSet<>();

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return containers.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return containers.isEmpty();
    }

    // other Collection methods implemented to delegate to containers
    // with some relationship management in add(Object) and remove(Object)
}
```

And here is a really simple test that demonstrates what I would like to do:

```
public class PersistenceTest {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public void testPersist() {
        ContainerCollection<> collection = new ContainerCollection<>();
        em.persist(collection);  // this line throws MappingException
    }

}
```

Comment: A JPA provider on its own should be able to support what you want (and I'm sure I've done that with DataNucleus JPA), so if it is just Spring getting in the way then raise a bug on them